# Trace dylib loading on Mac OSX

Tags: macos, qt, dylib

I'm trying to build a Qt-based application on Mac OSX, and something in my application bundle is pulling in a Qt library from /Library rather than from the application bundle.

I've done this successfully in the past, so I know about using install_name_tool to link applications and libraries to the bundle versions of libraries. I've done this, but I must be missing something. I've tried setting DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES, but I'm not really sure how this helps: I can see which Qt library is being pulled in from /Library first (QtXml), but I don't know which file in the bundle is pulling in this library.

Is there some trick to tracing back which file is loading a particular library?

Answer (score 1):

Use otool utility to see what libraries are used by your app and where the app expects to find them:

otool -L yourApp.app/Contents/MacOS/yourApp

Comment: Yeah, the trouble is that I have so many libraries and plugins in my application bundle, and I don't know which is the problem... my actual binary is just fine (and when setting DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES I can see that it's pulling in the right versions of the libraries). What I want is to trace back from the first "wrong" dylib to figure out what's pulling it in.